# Reduce function to delete duplicates - javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a set of Json Object. 
With a javascript map function I emit the name of a field with an array containing all its possible types. For example I have:

```
birthDate, [Date, String, String, String, String]
isMarried, [Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, String]
name, [String, String, String, String, String]
```

As you can see, each field is associated with an array containing all types under the form of String, duplicates too.
With my reduce function I have to delete duplicate:

```
reduce = function(key, stuff){return Array.unique(stuff).toString()}
```

Reduce function works for some types but it doesn't for other.

Comment: Got any examples where this is not working?

Comment: what is `Array.unique`? is this a library function?

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [
  ["birthDate", ["Date", "String", "String", "String", "String"]],
  ["isMarried", ["Boolean", "Boolean", "Boolean", "Boolean", "String"]],
  ["name", ["String", "String", "String", "String", "String"]]
];

function onlyUnique(value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

arr = arr.map( function(value){ console.log(value[1]);
   value[1] = value[1].filter(onlyUnique); return value;
} );
```